# What webcam is compatible with Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, webcam

Which webcam is compatible to Ubuntu 14.04? Have tried Logitech C270, but it is only for windows.

Comment: Apparently from a quick Google search, most people are perfectly able to use the c270 out of box since 12.04. How have you tried to use it?

Comment: This might be helpful. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam

Comment: I 've got Logitech Webcam C310 which also works fine.
I think all Logitech Webcams are OK with Ubuntu.

Comment: Very few OEMs won't talk about Ubuntu compatibility. Best to just plug it in and test and hunt for community-developed drivers

Answer (score 3):

The Logitech webcam C270 seems to work pretty well with Ubuntu actually, since quite some time.

One possible problem could be that there are [some issues](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1980235&p=13096398#post13096398) with connecting it to a USB3 port.
But that can easlily be worked around by using a USB2 port.

If it's not that - what makes you think it does not work well?

See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam

Answer (score 0):

I have only had experience with build-in webcams on the laptops that I owned and tried to run Ubuntu on. It worked flawless at least for Skype in all cases.

So I would guess, just try it! Even though the manufacturer only offers Windows driver downloads on their site, it doesn't mean that Linux doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult to provide a "full" list of compatible webcams, there are just too many to test them all. However, this webpage contains a good amount of information regarding the webcams supported by the `ov51x` driver:

http://ovcam.org/ov511/cameras.html